# MemoryError dealing with huge set of data from requests

Tags: python, pandas

I am downloading the Data from Rest API using requests and using data frame to download it in a flat file. I am getting the below memory Error. Any suggestion on resolving this?

```
File "C:\Python\Python37-32\my_script.py", line 74, in <module>
df1= pd.DataFrame(my_list)
File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 
435,
in __init__
arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 407, in to_arrays
coerce_float=coerce_float, dtype=dtype)
File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 477, in 
_list_of_dict_to_arrays
data = [(type(d) is dict) and d or dict(d) for d in data]
File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 477, in <listcomp>
data = [(type(d) is dict) and d or dict(d) for d in data]
MemoryError
```

Tried using the simplejson with stream=True

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
result = simplejson.loads(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of the dataset. If you are dealing with huge dataset which exceeds the limit of your local memory, you wont be able to do this operation. These libraries load the entire data directly into the memory, which in case of big data is never a good approach.

Comment: my data set is more than 4GB. Can you suggest what would be a correct way of doing this?What libraries should I be using?

Comment: There are a lot of libraries out there but which one to use depends on your use case. Start with Spark, which is a big data library and is widely used in the market.